# Make - Have master Makefile store intermediate files in type-specific temp folder

Tags: makefile

I have a 500+ line Makefile that is used to handle various automated builds. In its current state, it specifies a few rules, and depends on an argument being passed to `make` to determine which architecture to build for, ie:

```
all: release_build clean_all debug_build clean_all
```

So, on my build server, for example, I can generate tarballs of my project for multiple architectures like so:

```
make all ARCH=armhf
make all ARCH=x86
make all ARCH=x64
```

I'm attempting to parallelize builds to speed up how quickly the build server can give me the output of these builds, since CPU and IO-wise, it's underutilized. However, this leads to havok, as all the architectures use the same naming scheme for intermediate object files.

Is there a simple way to have my builds generate an intermediate folder like `.obj/${RELEASE_TYPE}/` to store the intermediate files? This would let me run debug and release builds in parallel

Thank you.

Comment: If the `ARCH` argument to make controls the architecture being built then you can't parallelize multiple architectures in a single `make` invocation with `-j#`. Using `-j#` *will* parallelize the building of targets for a single architecture as controlled by the value of `ARCH` in the `make all -j8 ARCH=XXXX` call. If `make all -j8 ARCH=armhf` breaks your build then your makefile is not correctly written. Which would not be at all surprising as many/most makefiles aren't.

Comment: @EtanReisner You are correct. I've updated my question. Is it at least possible to separate the debug and release builds for a single arch? ie: `./.obj/armhf/release, ./.obj/armhf/debug`, etc, to have intermediate objects stored in a temp folder like `.obj/${ARCH}/${RELEASE_TYPE}`? This way, I wouldn't have to issue `make clean` commands between builds for different arch and release types. Thank you!

Comment: That depends entirely on your makefile setup and how your rules are written. That's not something that make can do for you automagically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't sound difficult. (I could have sworn there was already a question like this...)

```
OBJECTS := foo.o bar.o

OBJDIR := ./.obj/$(ARCH)

all: release_build debug_build

RELEASEOBJECTS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/release/, $(OBJECTS))

release_build: $(RELEASEOBJECTS)
    do something with $^ to produce $@

DEBUGOBJECTS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/debug/, $(OBJECTS))

debug_build: $(DEBUGOBJECTS)
    do something with $^ to produce $@
```

With some further trickery you could have one rule for both builds, but it would be quite cryptic.